# How to perform left join using lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

What would be the lambda equivalent of the following SQL query:

```
  select a.name, s.color from table1 a
  left join [table2] s
  on a.id = s.id
```

Comment: It would be nice if you would put the link of the duplicate. smh

Comment: It does... at the top where it says **This question already has an answer here:**  *Lambda Expression for join*.